# How do I dock a UserControl into a FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: user-controls, dock, docking, flowlayoutpanel

I have a FlowLayoutPanel and a UserControl.

I've added multiple usercontrols into the `FlowLayoutPanel`, and I'm trying to dock them to the top, so when I change the size of the `FlowLayoutPanel` the size (width) of the usercontrols changes accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot dock anything inside a FlowLayoutPanel, it's simply ignored.

Check out the [answer here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/112563/flowlayoutpanel-does-not-respect-anchor-or-dock-properties-of-its-children) apparently posted by the Microsoft team.

They say:

> The FlowLayoutPanel relies on a largest control to effectively define the column/row within it. The code below set's the size of the first control to the width of the FLP to achieve a layout similar to what you want.

```
    private void flowLayoutPanel1_Layout(object sender, LayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[0].Dock = DockStyle.None;
        for (int i = 1; i < flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[i].Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        }
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[0].Width = flowLayoutPanel1.DisplayRectangle.Width - flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[0].Margin.Horizontal;

    }
```

Key thing is to use the `Layout` event.

This solution worked for me up to a point. Your UserControls have to have `AutoSize` turned off / stay a uniform size.

In my case I wanted `AutoSize` turned on so as to allow the UserControl to expand/contract vertically while filling the width of the FlowLayoutPanel.

I had to find a different solution. But the above might help you in your case.

Comment: thank you brother ^_^
iv managed to simulated that by changing the size of the controls when the size of the FlowLayoutPanel changes :)
i know that it may not be the best solution, but it did the work :D