# How do I add a SplitContainer dynamically c#

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel, splitcontainer

At design time I have a form with a FlowLayoutPanel. I can create buttons inside it with no problems. But when I tried to add a SplitContainer, nothing happens.

Later I will need to add a Splitcontainer inside another SplitContainer. So my user can choose the number of sections (panels) he wants to see in the form.

I'm trying this:

```
        SplitContainer spltcnt = new SplitContainer();
        spltcnt.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        spltcnt.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        spltcnt.SplitterWidth = 100;
        spltcnt.Visible = true;

        flwLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(spltcnt);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting DockStyle.Fill; on something inside a Flowlayout with the designer?  I suggest you set Height and Width instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't dock in a `FlowLayoutPanel` as per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880593/how-do-i-dock-a-usercontrol-into-a-flowlayoutpanel) (among others). You will have to manually set the `Height` and `Width` of your `SplitContainer`s when the form is resized.

Answer (score 0):

It's made, but the color is the same so you can't see it.

So, you can see it by changing the colors of Panel 1 and Panel 2.

```
        System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer spltcnt = 
               new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();

        spltcnt.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        spltcnt.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        spltcnt.SplitterWidth = 100;
        spltcnt.Visible = true;

        // color add.. I think it's because I can't see the color.
        spltcnt.Panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.GrayText;
        spltcnt.Panel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLight;

        panel1.Controls.Add(spltcnt);
```

Comment: This is an old question that has already been answered. If you want to add another answer, please make sure it provides new information in addition to what's already there, and please add some description, not only code.